# Exercise 8.6 of The TeXbook

Tags: tex-core, token-lists

> **Exercise 8.6**. Assume that the category codes of plain TEX are in force, except that the characters `^^A`, `^^B`, `^^C`, `^^M` belong respectively to categories 0, 7, 10, and 11. What tokens are produced from the (rather ridiculous) input line `^^B^^BM^^A^^B^^C^^M^^@\M␣`? (Remember that this line is followed by ⟨return⟩, which is `^^M`; and recall that `^^@` denotes the ⟨null⟩ character, which has category 9 when INITEX begins.)

To recall, `0` is for escape, `7` is for superscript, `10` is for space, and `11` is for letters.

The answer given is:
`^^B`<sub>7</sub>
`^^B`<sub>7</sub>
`M`<sub>11</sub>
`|^^B|`
`␣`<sub>10</sub>
`^^M`<sub>7</sub>
`|M^^M|`.
(I have used `|cs|` to denote the control sequence name "cs".)

**Question:** Why is `␣`<sub>10</sub> there!? Firstly, `^^C` is a non-letter character that follows `^^A^^B` (an escape character followed by a non-letter), and thus goes into state S (*not* M), and it's clearly written that in such a case, any space character is "simply passed by".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in page 47:

> if TeX sees a character of category 10, the action depends on the current state. If is in state N or S it is passed by and remained in same state. Otherwise in state M the character is converted to space (character code 32) with catcode 10, and entering state S. The character code in a space token is always 32.

And on page 46,

> If TeX sees a category 0 in any state, …
> (b) if the next character is not of category 11, the name consists of that symbol. … This name becomes a control sequence token. TeX goes to state S … in case (b) with respect to a character of category 10, otherwise TeX goes into state M.

So it is in state M after `^^A^^B`, because `^^B` is not of category 10.

Comment: Ah! I had earlier thought that "with respect to a character of cat 10" meant that TeX will ignore any character of cat 10. The wording stumped me.

Answer (score 5):

after an escape character followed by a character not of catcode 11, tex goes in to state M unless the character was a space.  so spaces are skipped after `\`  but not after `\$` or after `^^A^^B`